# jquery selectors: how to select all li items from some index to the end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

So we can select one item `li:eq('+(lastItemIndex)+')'` I wonder how to select this item and all items that are next from it to the end?  [jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/LN6ak/1/) (in which we would like to change all elements in li from `3` to `last one`)

Comment: I wonder about `li` items selectors, not about how to select all items that belong to cless `toHide`=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [nextAll();](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```
var lastItemIndex = 3;
$('li').eq(lastItemIndex).nextAll('li').css("opacity", 0);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LN6ak/2/

Answer (score 0):

use
    li:gt('+(lastItemIndex - 1)+')'

heres your updated code

http://jsfiddle.net/LN6ak/3/

[jQuery(':gt(index)')](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) Selects all elements greater than given index.
Subtracting one from your lastItemIndex to get 'greater than or equal to' :)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `:gt` and `:lt` to create yourself a range selector

```
 $('ul li:gt(2):lt('+$('ul li').length+')')
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LN6ak/4/)